# Measuring inter-community interactivity in a network

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, modularity, gephi

#### Question

I have a directional network where the nodes are unique users, and the edges indicate retweets. I've imported into Gephi and used its modularity measure for community detection and now have a community label for each user.

The clustering has worked well, but now I'd like to know the degree to which users in each group interact with users outside of their community. Is there a statistic from graph theory designed for this question (preferably implemented in Gephi or Networkx)?

I have tried my own crude measure detailed below, but would prefer a better measure if there is one.

#### My (crude) Method

So far I have done this by generating a table in Pandas that shows...

```
interaction_df (pd.DateFrame)
    source_user  target user  source_class  target_class  inter_group_interaction
    a            b            5             5             False
    a            c            5             8             True             
    b            c            5             8             True
    c            d            8             10            True
    d            e            10            10            False
    e            a            10            5             True
```

...and then....

```
interaction_counts = interaction_df.groupby('source_class').sum()['inter_group_interaction']
source_class
5     2.0
8     1.0
10    1.0
Name: inter_group_interaction, dtype: float64
```

...gives me a count of how many instances of `inter_group_interaction` occurs for each community `class`. If I divide this by the number of unique users in each group I get a comparable measure of `inter_group_interaction`...

```
group_counts = interaction_df.drop_duplicates('source_user').source_class.value_counts()
5     2
10    2
8     1
Name: source_class, dtype: int64

interaction_counts / group_counts
5     1.0
8     1.0
10    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Indicating that users in community `10` are half as interactive with users outside their community as the other two communities.

Comment: I think the measure that you are looking for is [homophily/assortative mixing](https://www.sci.unich.it/~francesc/teaching/network/assortative.html). However, these measures are very related to the notion of modularity, so there is a certain circularity if you quantify the homophily of nodes that are in different classes precisely because they are in different modules.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just what I was after. I take your point on the circularity of the process as well. Whilst I'm measuring modularity based on one set of edge criteria I plan on looking at homophilly through other forms of interaction so I'm hoping it is ultimately not too circular. You should put this as an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one.

Comment: You might also consider comparing the ratio of edges within a community to all edges adjacent to nodes in the community (intra/(intra+inter)) for each community.